# Error: package android.util does not exist

Tags: java, android, compilation

I am trying to compile my java code, so I first convert it to .class, then to .dex and finally to smali, this has always worked, except for now as I am using the method `Log.e()` instead of `System.out.println()` to log some errors; I am unable to convert the .java file to .class.

This is the command I launch to get the .class file:

`$ javac helloworld.java`

Even though I've imported the library `import android.util.Log;`
 I get the following Error:

> sources/com/canal/android/external/CplusJni.java:9: error: package android.util does not exist
>   import android.util.Log;
>                      ^
>
> sources/com/canal/android/external/CplusJni.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
>
> Log.e("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
>
> ^
>
> symbol:   variable Log
>
> location: class CplusJni
>
> sources/com/canal/android/external/CplusJni.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
>   Log.e("cplusPKCS12Cert: ",cplusPKCS12Cert);
>
> ^
>
> symbol:   variable Log
>
> location: class CplusJni
>
> sources/com/canal/android/external/CplusJni.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
>
> Log.e("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
>
> ^
>
> symbol:   variable Log
>
> location: class CplusJni
>
> sources/com/canal/android/external/CplusJni.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
>
> Log.e("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
>   ^
>    symbol:   variable Log
>
> location: class CplusJni
>
> sources/com/canal/android/external/CplusJni.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
>
> Log.e("sSLSocketFactory: ",sSLSocketFactory);
>
> ^
>
> symbol:   variable Log
>
> location: class CplusJni
>
> sources/com/canal/android/external/CplusJni.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
>
> Log.e("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
>
> ^
>
> symbol:   variable Log
>
> location: class CplusJni
>
> 7 errors

Here is my code:

```
package com.canal.android.external;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import android.util.Log;`

public class CplusJni {
public static native byte[] getCplusPKCS12Cert();

public static native byte[] getCplusPKCS12Pass();

static {
    System.loadLibrary("cplusnative");
}

public static SSLSocketFactory a() {
    SSLSocketFactory sSLSocketFactory = null;
    try {
        SSLContext instance = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        byte[] cplusPKCS12Cert = getCplusPKCS12Cert();
        Log.e("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Log.e("cplusPKCS12Cert: ",cplusPKCS12Cert);
        Log.e("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(cplusPKCS12Cert);
        KeyStore instance2 = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        byteArrayInputStream.close();
        KeyManagerFactory instance3 = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
        instance.init(instance3.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(instance.getSocketFactory());
        sSLSocketFactory = instance.getSocketFactory();
        Log.e("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Log.e("sSLSocketFactory: ",sSLSocketFactory);
        Log.e("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        return sSLSocketFactory;
    } catch (Exception unused) {
        return sSLSocketFactory;
    }
}
}
```

I would appreciate some help with this!

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @ismailalaoui can you please check my post, I've added the code.

Comment: can i check you app gradle dependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

try to solve it this way

Step by step:

1- Open Auto Import settings

2- Switch off Optimize imports on the fly

3- Remove class in Exclude list

Comment: I can't find `Auto import settings` on android studio's settinhgs, I'm on Linux.